# Opening Excel 2016 file on other system

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I did my assignment in excel and want to send the file to our professor by Email . I want to make sure that he can open the file without any problem. I am using excel 2016. can file be open on other computer regard of what version of excel he use? Or is there any setting that I can use to make sure my file can be open on other computer?

**EDIT:** I saved the file as ".xls" format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel files in Windows are saved in XLXS format by default. This format has been used since Office 2010 or possibly earlier.

So, yes (99%) your Professor will be able to open the file.

Office has really included interoperability for a very long time.

In the unlikely event, Prof has a very old system, you can resave the file as XLS and send that to accommodate.

With reasonable care (using normal features), Office for Windows files are interoperable with Office for MAC as well.

Answer (score 1):

This may just be a matter of preference — as well as any requirements your professor should themselves have set forth explicitly — but if it were me, I would cover all my bases by sending the document as a .pdf file so that it looks presentable and more professional (you can use Save As and select .pdf file format), and somewhere on the document itself (header/footer, unless it's updated dynamically) I would include links to hosted versions of the spreadsheet version ***or*** use a companion page that enumerates the relevant cell formulas, e.g., =FORMULATEXT(), etc.  The spreadsheets themselves should be .xlsx for updated formatting conventions, and they can use Office online to open these up; as academic educators, it would not make any sense for them to not have Office 365 since (to my knowledge) they get it for either free or a discounted rate, as Microsoft offers a special program for them.  If you want to be careful, you can also include another link to a Google Sheets version, which you should be able to upload and convert from .xlsx directly.  Note that they are not 100% interoperable with each other, but as a generalization the majority of their functions are compatible.

And finally, since you are dealing with multiple document formats saved to different sources, document version control becomes a key, and it's up to you to maintain and control this.  Make sure all access privileges are set to View Only, and you upkeep certain information such as `Created By`, `Revised/Reviewed By`, `Creation Date`, `Review Date`, `Revision Date`, `Version Number`, `Approved By`, etc.  Depending on the discipline/industry you're studying in, document control procedures may vary widely, but you can reference ISO or GFSI benchmarked standards as a source of reference if strict accountability is required (you may need to create a tracking log in that case), but otherwise this shouldn't be necessary.